# rosversion ros issue in Groovy

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used to use rosversion to confirm to *'everything is all right'* notion and it worked fine in Electric and Fuerte. However now I am using Groovy and everything is about okay and till now I have tried simple programs and things are fine, I am still using rosbuild and my .bashrc is setup like this;

> source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

> source ~/groovy_workspace/setup.bash

but

> rosversion ros

gives a

> Cannot locate [ros]

output -- much to my annoyance ! Any solutions ?  Is it just me or is it a common problem ?

**UPDATE**

Following the advice of KruseT,

> rosversion roslang

gives

> 1.9.39

is that the correct version of groovy release ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51348/rosversion-ros-issue-in-groovy/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What had been the "ros" stack is now a metapackage. metapackages consist only of a package.xml (stating the version), and this currently does not get installed.

You can now get the same effect by calling

```
$ rosversion roslang
```

or using any other package name, instead of a "stack" name.

EDIT:
I created a report here: https://github.com/ros/rospkg/issues/18
But the root problem here is that for meta-packages, the meta-information (such as version), does not get installed, so not sure whether you'll ever be able to call rosversion ros with a useful result again.

EDIT: ROS Groovy comes released with 1.9 as major and minor versions. So it seems right. For more detailed answer, ask a new different question.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-03**:
@KruseT Thank you -- I would guess that there should be a command line tool to check for the version of a software, this is probably a part of 'best practices' of ros (typically any software)

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-03**:
The appropriate way of checking the version of installed ROS is: $ dpkg -l ros-groovy-ros